# Kohana Framework: 'HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL welcome/index was not found on this server.'

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

[I followed this tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials/hello-world#hello-world) with only one difference. Instead of naming it hello.php, I named it welcome.php. The sources of my files are identical to that of the tutorials, and they are in the correct paths. What could cause this?

I am referencing it with 'kohana/index.php/welcome' as per the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your controller's name to Welcome instead of Hello

```
Class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {
   public function action_index()
  {
      echo 'hello, world!';
  }
}
```

I guess you forgot to change the controller name?

Answer (score 2):

> I named it welcome.php. The sources of
>   my files are identical to that of the
>   tutorials

if that is so, you need to rename your controller Controller_Welcome instead of Controller_Hello